# Is there a way to block EasyMock's nice control in a java project?

Tags: java, spring, testing, easymock

In my project we use `EasyMock` in tests for createing mock objects.
We decided to prevent the usage of `createNiceControl()` in every tests.
Is there a way to prevent it in a Java 11 application?

Comment: I don't know of any method called `niceControl`. Are you talking about `createNiceControl()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm asking about `createNiceControl()`

Answer (score 0):

Not directly with EasyMock no. But you can easily add a ArchUnit or a Checkstyle rule.